# Is there a way to specify which of the two emails' contents to check using Mail::assertSent in Laravel project?

Tags: phpunit, laravel-9

I would like to test the contents of two emails sent in a Laravel project.

If I do the following, "2emails" will be sent.

`$this->email($data);`

The following assert goes through and the test succeeds.

`Mail::assertSent(BuildMessage::class, 2);`

However, I can only see the contents of the first email.

```
Mail::assertSent(BuildMessage::class, 2); //true

Mail::assertSent(BuildMessage::class, function ($mail) {

            $mail->build();

            dd($mail); //dump
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　・・・・・・
```

The result of dd() was the content of the first email as shown below.

```
App\Mail\BuildMessage^ {#15539 
  +data: array:4 [
    "to" => "first@example.com"
    "subject" => "1st subject"
    "text" => "aaaaaaaa"
 +from: array:1 [
    0 => array:2 [
      "name" => "test sender"
      "address" => "sender@admin.com"
    ]
  ]
  +to: array:1 [
    0 => array:2 [
      "name" => null
      "address" => "first@example.com"
    ]
  ]
  +cc: []
  +bcc: []
  +replyTo: []
  +subject: "1st subject"
```

Searching the Internet, I found "how many mails were sent" and "how to assert the contents of the email," but no way to confirm the contents of each of the first and second mails.

How can I explicitly specify the 1st and 2nd email to check the content?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to use Mail::assertSent, but now I can check it by writing the following.

```
    $mails = Mail::sent(BuildMessage::class);

    $mail01 = $mails[0];
    $mail02 = $mails[1];

    $this->assertEquals('1st subject', $mail01->data['subject']);
    $this->assertEquals('2nd subject', $mail02->data['subject']);
```